# Applying Pandas iterrows function

Tags: python, loops

I was wondering whether somebody could please give me some assistance with the Pandas iterrows package.

I'm currently using an iterative function which works but I was wondering whether using iterrows would make it more efficient to avoid a for loop?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframe_1 = pd.read_csv("D\data\2018_19.csv")

def append_date_column(df):

df = df.copy()

df['date_column'] = np.nan

date_range = pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2001', periods = 207, freq = 'M').values

for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    date_number = df.loc[row, "income2"]
    if (not pd.isna(date_number)) and date_number < 207:
        date = date_range[int(date_number) -1]
        df.loc[row, 'date_column'] = date

df_with_date_column = df

return df_with_date_column
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it and time it.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input and expected output so that we can better understand your issue. It looks like you might not need to iterate at all, if I understand the issue there's likely a vectorized way to do what you're trying to do